# Changing the format from numeric to POSIXct object in R

Tags: r, posixct

I have a column containing these dates and times:

```
20121029 0,
20121029 100,
20121029 200,
20121029 300,
20121029 400 ...
```

their format is "int"

My task is to change them and create a column in POSIXct format that represents  the  time  and  date.

Comment: Do you mean that you have two columns, each an int?

Comment: Does the `0, 100, 200` etc represent the time of day (presumably in 24 hour time, or is it unrelated to the dates/times?

Comment: G5W yes. User5783745, yes it represents the time of day in 24h time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution, but it works

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

example_data <- c("20121029 0", "20121029 100", "20121029 2100")

# Extract the times
times <- example_data %>% strsplit(. , " ") %>% sapply(. , "[", 2)
times <- str_pad(times, max(nchar(times)), side="right", pad="0")

# Extract just the dates
dates <- example_data %>% substr(., 1, 8)

# Combine date and time and convert to POSIXct
date_time <- paste(dates, times) %>% as.POSIXct(., format="%Y%m%d %H%M")
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It helped me a lot!